Ubuntu 22.04 Boots to Black Screen with Blinking line
I am new to Ubuntu and decided to use ChatGPT to help me fix a graphical problem. My PC no longer boots. I will try to share chat when available (currently I get error every time i click 'share').

Ubuntu 22.04 boots to a black screen with a visible cursor solution step was already done, so it was of no use on my PC.
System Specifications:

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.5
Kernel: 6.8.0-40-generic
CPU: Intel i9 gen-13
GPU: NVIDIA RTX 4090
NVIDIA Driver Version: 555.58.02
Desktop Environment: GNOME
Display Manager: GDM (gdm3)

When I boot my system, it goes to a black screen with a blinking cursor in the top-left corner instead of the graphical login screen. I can access TTY terminals using Ctrl+Alt+F1 through F6, but the GUI does not start.
System logs for error testing:
(used image2text and a lot of manual typing, so there may be slight output errors)

startx

fatal server error: (EE) failed to create screen resources(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to x server: connection refused
xinit: server error


sudo systemctl status gdm

gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static)
     Active: active (running)

Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Gdm: Child process was already dead.
gdm-launch-environment]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Gdm: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: maximum number of X display failures reached: check X server log for errors


sudo journalctl -p err -b

gdm-launch-environment][5812]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
systemd[5244]: Failed to start Dunst notification daemon.
systemd[5244]: Failed to start Daemon to manage razer devices in user-space.
Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Gdm: Child process was already dead.
Gdm: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: maximum number of X display failures reached: check X server log for errors
kernel: i2c i2c-2: Failed to register i2c client ITE8853:00 at 0x4e (-16)
kernel: Serial bus multi instantiate pseudo device driver INT3515:00: error -ENXIO: IRQ index 1 not found
kernel: uvcvideo 1-3.3:1.1: Failed to set UVC probe control: -32 (exp. 26).
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Invalid buffer destination
kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS


cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep "(EE)"

(EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -2
(EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: -19
(EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
(EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
(EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
(EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
(EE) no screens found(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.


lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D'

VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corpotation Device 2684 (rev a1)
Subsystem: ZOTAC International ltd device
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidi*a


nvidia-smi

No errors. Graphics card and driver both appear.

"decided to use ChatGPT" ugh. What exactly did you do to break it?

@OrganicMarble im not sure I was using the new GPT-o1 and it gave me a long list of steps: that involved modprobe, nouveau, xorg. It initially asked for me to run some tests, which made me feel like it knew what it was doing. I think part of the problem is that the model is set to temperature 1, so its a lot more randomized.

Initially the problem was just screen tearing while watching media or playing games. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
Which broke chrome.
Tried fixing, then desktop stopped booting (image above)
Tried fixing, then it began freezing on ubuntu loading screen. I managed to get in to grub menu, and boot in recovery mode, from there I had to manually connect to wifi (took 12 commands just to connect), but it would crash and require rebooting after simple commands: e.g. "apt update").

You are in terminal mode. This command worked for me. Type it in at the blinking cursor, then it will ask for your password. After entering your password, follow the instructions on screen.
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop


What you referred to as "terminal mode" is usually called a virtual console.
